# How do I return an object with fields in R?

Tags: r

I have a function that looks like the following. I want to read in a CSV file, and then split the data into two groups.

```
loadData <- function(f) {
 rdata <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE);
 rdata$class <- factor(rdata$class);
 rdata.a <- subset(rdata, class == 0);
 rdata.b <- subset(rdata, class == 1);
 return(rdata);
}
```

I then call the function like the following.

```
rdata <- loadData("/path/to/data.csv");
```

However, when I try to reference rdata.a (or rdata.b), I get the following message.

> Error: object 'rdata.a' not found

However, I can still reference the returned object "as normal"

> class(radata)
>
> > [1] "data.frame"

How do I revise the function so that the fields (a and b) are also returned?

Please note that if this code does not live inside a function, then everything works as expected (I can reference rdata.a and rdata.b).

Comment: Couldn't you just do `rdata <- read.csv("/path/to/data.csv"); split(rdata, rdata$class)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects `rdata`, `rdata.b` and `rdata.b` are two unrelated objects. The dot has no special meaning in R, as it would in Java or Python for instance. To return your two subsets, you need to put them in a list. Also, no need for the semicolons at the end of lines:

```
loadData <- function(f) {
  rdata <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
  rdata$class <- factor(rdata$class)
  rdata.a <- subset(rdata, class == 0)
  rdata.b <- subset(rdata, class == 1)
  return(list(rdata.a, rdata.b))
}

rdata <- loadData("/path/to/data.csv")
```

Then you can access them with `rdata[[1]]` and `rdata[[2]]`.

Comment: And you could name them `a` and `b` for convenient reference later

Comment: ,..yes (`list(a=rdata.a, b=rdata.b)`) and access them with `rdata$a` and `rdata$b` or `rdata[['a']]` and `rdata[['b']]`, thx Richard.